# php : A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to get the users age, i am getting the corrrect output but with a warning in my html page

Error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: A non well formed numeric value encountered
Filename: controllers/users.php
Line Number: 45
```

Code i used is :

```
$now = time();
$data['dob'] =  strftime('%Y', $now)-strftime('%Y',$query['dob']);   //it should be showig user age
```

what could be the reason for the above shown error, Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i converted the string into int , and subtracted the value to get my output

`$userdob=(int)$query['dob'];
        $data['dob'] =   strftime('%Y', $now)- strftime('%Y',$userdob);`

Answer (score 2):

`strftime` returns a string, you must convert it to number before subtraction.

EDIT: seeing the comment below, you cannot subtract, as `dob` is not in the same format returned by `time()`. So, proceed as in the paragraph above.

EDIT2: cleanest way to subtract two dates is [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: can you explain your answer with few codes, because i am not understanding your sentances.

Comment: `So, proceed as in the paragraph above.` which paragraph?  This `strftime('%Y',$query['dob'])` is in string format , how can i convert it to the correct format to get the correct output?

Comment: Because I assumed that `dob` was something that is not.

Comment: "you must convert it to number before subtraction", so either put `(int)` in front of each of the `strftime` calls, like `(int) strftime(…)` or wrap them into a call to `intval`. Or use DateTime (better).

Answer (score -1):

It is probably because $query['dob'] contains something other than an integer.

strftime() expects it's second argument to be a timestamp (that is, a unix-timestamp, an integer representing seconds past the epoch).  If I had to guess, I'd guess that you're $query['dob'] contains some kind of string.

Comment: may be because i provided dob, from jquery date picker, which stores my date in this format `1949-05-11`  . Then what should i do to solve this problem?

Comment: can you explain with code? Because your answer goes over my head